# Full calendar event color

Tags: angular

ERROR: The expected type comes from property 'color' which is declared here on type Calendar Event
Type 'string' is not assignable to type Event Color

angular 8

Answer (score 0):

define your colors like this

```js
export const colors: any = {
  red: {
    primary: '#ad2121',
    secondary: '#FAE3E3'
  },
  blue: {
    primary: '#1e90ff',
    secondary: '#D1E8FF'
  },
  yellow: {
    primary: '#e3bc08',
    secondary: '#FDF1BA'
  }
};
```

and then in the event use like this

```js
color: colors.yellow
```